# problem with y label and x label

Tags: labels, axis, tikz-pic

I have a problem with the axis labels. When I scale down the graph it changes my location and they don't look like they should. If I set the scale to 1 it looks good but I change the scale and mess up the axis labels(ylabel and xlabel).

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
    \begin{axis}[
axis lines=center,
grid={both}, 
clip=false,
grid style={solid,black!75},
y axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},
x axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},
ytick={0,2}, 
xmin=-0.5,xmax=4.5,
ymax=4,ymin=-1,
extra y ticks={-1,3,4},
extra y tick labels={},
extra y tick style={ticklabel style={fill=none}},
minor tick num=1,
ylabel={$i_{(t)}$}, xlabel={$t$},
ylabel style={above}, 
xlabel style={right}, 
ticklabel style={fill=black!20,circle,inner sep=2pt},
scale only axis,
width=8cm,
height=4cm
]
% changed from draw to addplot
\addplot [ultra thick,blue] coordinates{(0,2)(0.5,2)};
\addplot [ultra thick,blue] coordinates{(2.5,2)(3,2)};
\addplot[ultra thick,blue,domain=0.5:2.5,samples=100)]{-2*sin(deg(pi*x/2-pi/4))+2};
\addplot[ultra thick,blue,dashed,domain=3:4,samples=100)]{-2*sin(deg(pi*x/2-3*pi/2))+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a sufficiently high version of pgfplots. Any version `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` or higher is sufficient, but of course it is worthwhile to fully update the TeX installation and choose `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
    \begin{axis}[
      axis lines=center,
      grid={both}, 
      clip=false,
      grid style={solid,black!75},
      y axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},
      x axis line style={very thick,-Stealth},
      ytick={0,2}, 
      xmin=-0.5,xmax=4.5,
      ymax=4,ymin=-1,
      extra y ticks={-1,3,4},
      extra y tick labels={},
      extra y tick style={ticklabel style={fill=none}},
      minor tick num=1,
      ylabel={$i_{(t)}$}, xlabel={$t$},
      ylabel style={above}, 
      xlabel style={right}, 
      ticklabel style={fill=black!20,circle,inner sep=2pt},
      scale only axis,
      width=8cm,
      height=4cm
      ]
% changed from draw to addplot
\addplot [ultra thick,blue] coordinates{(0,2)(0.5,2)};
\addplot [ultra thick,blue] coordinates{(2.5,2)(3,2)};
\addplot[ultra thick,blue,domain=0.5:2.5,samples=100)]{-2*sin(deg(pi*x/2-pi/4))+2};
\addplot[ultra thick,blue,dashed,domain=3:4,samples=100)]{-2*sin(deg(pi*x/2-3*pi/2))+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For the future I'd kindly like to ask you to provide the community with minimal but *complete* codes, which begin with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you so much!